# DD-WRT commands that worked on ASUS RT-N16 not working on new router, ASUS RT-AC68U

Tags: networking, router, vpn, dd-wrt

I have some startup and firewall commands that don't seem to be working on my "new" router that worked perfectly on my old one. The startup command should allow me to tunnel into my work network using pretty standard OpenVPN scripts and the firewall is just 4 lines with iptables adjustments.

I flashed the router twice, first with the stock build, DD-WRT v3.0-r40559 std (08/06/19), then after reading that there were possible VPN issues with that one, I re-flashed to DD-WRT v3.0-r41813 std (12/29/19). Everything else works great.

So my new router is on DD-WRT v3.0-r41813 std (12/29/19) and the old one was on DD-WRT v24-sp2 (04/13/11) big.

**The start-up code follows (masking IP and static key):**
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

## Move to writable directory and create scripts

cd /tmp
ln -s /usr/sbin/openvpn /tmp/myvpn

## Config for Wes-to-Office

echo "
remote XX.XX.XXX.XXX
proto udp
port 4194
dev tun0
secret /tmp/static.key
verb 3
comp-lzo
keepalive 15 60
daemon
" > Wes-Office.conf

## Config for Static Key

echo "
-----BEGIN OpenVPN Static key V1-----
xxxxxTHE VERY LONG STATIC KEY IS HEREXXXXX
-----END OpenVPN Static key V1-----
" > static.key

## Create interface to ALD

/tmp/myvpn --mktun --dev tun0
ifconfig tun0 xx.xx.xx.x netmask 255.255.255.0 promisc up
route add -net 192.168.XX.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw xx.xx.xx.x
route add -net 192.168.XX.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw xx.xx.xx.x
route add -net 192.168.XX.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw xx.xx.xx.x
route add -net 192.168.XX.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw xx.xx.xx.x
route add -net 192.168.XX.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw xx.xx.xx.x
route add -net 192.168.XX.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw xx.xx.xx.x

## Initiate the tunnel

sleep 5
/tmp/myvpn --config Wes-Office.conf
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

**The Firewall code follows:**
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

## Open firewall holes for VPN

iptables -I INPUT 2 -p udp --dport 4194 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -i br0 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -i tun0 -o br0 -j ACCEPT

## Allow ping over VPN

iptables -I INPUT 3 -i tun0 -p icmp -j ACCEPT
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Comment: You should edit your question and indicate what commands are. It working.  What version of DD-WRT was the other router using?

Comment: @Ramhound I've added the code and other information. Thanks for any feedback you might have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!
after adding 'modprobe tun' into the start script, it works.
Sometime between builds, it must have been turned off by default.